# How SupportVectors are derived and used to predict a label?

Tags: c++, opencv

`A` is a 3 by 3 matrix for training and `b` is a vector or labels.

```
Mat A(3, 3, CV_32FC1);
Mat b(3, 1, CV_32S);    

for (int r = 1; r < 4; r++) {
    for (int c = 2; c < 5; c++)
        A.at<float>(r-1, c-2) = r * c;
    b.row(r-1) = r;
}
```

These were used as

```
Ptr<SVM> svm = SVM::create();
svm->setType(SVM::C_SVC);
svm->setKernel(SVM::LINEAR);
svm->train(A, ROW_SAMPLE, b);
```

and after training svm obtained a 3 by 3 matrix or `supportVectors`. 1st and 3rd row of `supportVectors` are same and the 2nd one is half of 1st/3rd. How it is computed?

If I give it a vector with 3 components, it can predict. `s` is a row vector

```
float array[] = { 8, 10, 12 };
Mat s(1, 3, CV_32FC1, &array);
```

and `svm->predict(s)` gives me 3? How?

Is there any math reference with example for supportVectors and prediction?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine

Comment: So, LINEAR is only for binary classification? In addition to @Miki 's link interested one can find numeric examples [here](http://axon.cs.byu.edu/Dan/678/miscellaneous/SVM.example.pdf).